# How to find multiple non-consecutive letters within a file name

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, filenames

I have a directory with files named hello, help, helol, llala, lalala, hi.
I need to be able to list only files with at least 2 l's in their name and these l's cannot be consecutive (unless there is still another l which is not consecutive). Therefore only helol, llala and lalala should be listed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use glob pattern:

```
*l[^l]*l*
```

- `[^l]` matches any character except `l`
- `*` matches zero or more characters
- `l` matches literal `l`

**Example:**

```
$ ls
hello  helol  help  hi  lalala  llala

$ ls *l[^l]*l*
helol  lalala  llala
```